# Changing content of a div on button click

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my button:

```
<p>File Uploaded:</p><fieldset><div id='fileloc'>"PROGRAMMATICALLY INSERTED LINK TO FILE" <button type='button' onclick='fileDelete()'>Delete</button></div></fieldset>
```

And here's my script to try to replace the values in the div with an upload button.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var fileDelete = function() {
            var delDiv = document.getElementById("fileloc")
            delDiv.value('<p>Upload Support Document</p><fieldset><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></fieldset>');
        }
    </script>
```

However I get the error:

delDiv.value is not a function.

Would I run document.delDiv? How would I go about doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a value, it's inner markup. Try this:

```
delDiv.innerHTML = '<p>Upload Support Document</p><fieldset><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></fieldset>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `delDiv.innerHTML = '<p>...';` instead. The `value` attribute exists typically for `<input>` elements, not `<div>`s.

Also, any reason you're doing `var fileDelete = function() {}` vs. `function fileDelete() {}`? See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) for the difference and whether one way applies to your problem over the other.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it's `value` that you want, but `innerHTML`

`document.getElementById("fileloc").innerHTML = '<p>Upload Support Document</p><fieldset><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></fieldset>';`

Answer (score 1):

Use `delDiv.innerHTML = '<p>...</p>';`

Answer (score 0):

you should be changing the innerHtml element instead

```
delDiv.innerHtml = 'your html';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the innerHTML property:

```
delDiv.innerHTML = '<p>Upload Support Document</p><fieldset><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></fieldset>'
```

Answer (score 0):

value is a property of the element, so it is set through the assignment operator:

```
delDiv.value =
    '<p>Upload Support Document</p><fieldset><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></fieldset>';
```

However, I think your intent here is to set the HTML inside:

```
delDiv.innerHTML = 
    '<p>Upload Support Document</p><fieldset><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></fieldset>';
```

...oh, and you forgot a semicolon on the previous line ;)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I imagine you were downvoted for introducing a SyntaxError by including an unescaped *LineTerminator* into your string literals.

Comment: Yikes... I'm stuck in PHP mode. Fixed it... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should use `innerHTML` : `delDiv.innerHTML = "..."`